# How to make Take() and Skip() modular?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, modular, skip-take

I have a struct like this:

```
public struct Response
{
    public string Cmd;
}
```

And also in main I'm having this byte array:

```
Decode(StringToByteArray("0100002402433131000000000000000311"));
```

And then I have a decode function inside this function I want to do Take(5) and Skip (3) like this:

```
byte[] cmd = resp.Skip(5).Take(3).ToArray();
x.Cmd = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cmd);
```

How can i make this Modular as i need to the same to many function that might be the position is different is there anyway that instead of using Take(3) or Skip (5) i can assign Variable to calculate this automatically?

Comment: Create a function for that?

Comment: And pass 5 and 3 as argument to that function?

Comment: How?! i should't touch the Modularity of my existing function as my Communication will follow my standard however i need to replace Take(3) with Something that like Take(bcmd.Length ) so far im having Error on that because of the different data type

Comment: This 5 and 3 position will be different in another Decode strings i need something more smart to calculate and estimate the position base of Cmd Size

Comment: @Artinos: "i should't touch the Modularity of my existing function as my Communication will follow my standard " -- I can't begin to fathom what this means.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your other function:

```
public T[] SkipTake<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int skipCount, int takeCount) {
    return items.Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount).ToArray();
}
```

It uses generics, so I'd read up on those (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Personally ild make it an extention method, (same idea as @siride but a bit more fluent)

eg

```
public static class SkipTakeExtentions{
    public static T[] SkipTake<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int skipCount, int takeCount) {
        return items.Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount).ToArray();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
thing.SkipTake(1,2);
```